# Update Template Parameter/Recast Template With New Parameter

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm creating a tree of templated typenames. I am using tuples for the trees structure. Every `Node` in the tree that is not a `leaf` will contain a tuple of typenames containing other `Nodes` and `Leaves`. The leaves will contain a `size` and an `offset` representing their position within the tuple (relative to root node and based on the `size` of the leaf nodes before it). Essentially all values will be known at compile time, I would like to use the tuple as a map of sorts. The end result will look something like so:

[image: Tuple Overview]

Simple enough, I create a variadic template note and unpack the result into a tuple for the nodes

```
template<typename... Elements>
struct Node {
    std::tuple<Elements...> elements;
};
```

But the catch is that I would like both the `Nodes` and the `leaves` to contain a template argument for their offset position within the tuple, that way I can access "Leaf 4" for example from Node 1 by using `std::get<0>(std::get<1>(Node0))`, and from within "Node 2" I could access its elements each of which would still know their offset within the "grander tuple". Programmatically this would look something like so (albeit below does not account for the offset part):

```
template<uint16_t offset, uint16_t size>
struct Leaf {
    constexpr uint16_t GetOffset() {return offset; }
    constexpr uint16_t GetSize() {return size; }
};

template<uint16_t offset, typename... Elements>
struct Node {
    std::tuple<Elements...> elements;  //Does not setup proper offsets
    
    constexpr uint16_t GetOffset() { return offset; }
};
```

As you can see I have a tuple of elements but I would need to "Recast" them into new templates using a new offset based on the size of the leaves prior. So, along the lines of "Recasting" my next idea was this:

```
template<uint16_t offset, uint16_t size>
struct Leaf {
    static constexpr uint16_t GetOffset() {return offset; }
    static constexpr uint16_t GetSize() {return size; }

    //New ability to Recast
    template<uint16_t newOffset>
    struct Recast {
        typedef Leaf<newOffset, size> type;
    };
};

template<uint16_t offset, typename... Elements>
struct Node {

    static constexpr uint16_t GetSize() {
        return (Elements::GetSize() + ...);
    }

    static constexpr auto GetElements() {
        uint16_t size = 0;
        //Using the comma operator to increment size before recasting using it
        return std::tuple<(Elements::template Recast<(size+= Elements::GetSize(), size)>::type)...>
    }
    static constexpr auto elements = GetElements();

    static constexpr uint16_t GetOffset() { return offset; }

    //New ability to Recast
    template<uint16_t newOffset>
    struct Recast {
        typedef Node<newOffset, Elements...> type;
    };
};
```

But now I'm running into issues where `size` can't be used as a constant expression and even if it was the increment would come before it was used as an offset by the recast due to the order of operations using the comma operator. Long story short, how can I make this vision a reality, is their a tweak I can make to the existing setup or is there a different tool that I should be using that would help simplify this whole thing?

To potentially clear things up I am using template arguments to store the offset because that way I can ensure that it can be evaluated at compile time and so that the data memory storage of such values is unnecessary. Basically I want to make sure that if these values are going to be inlined anyways that they aren't also taking up space on the stack or heap. If there is another way to accomplish something similar that would be perfect as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I don't quite get the exact logic how the code work, but you might try this:

```cpp
struct Node {
     ⋮
     ⋮
    template<uint16_t ... I, uint16_t ... J>
    static constexpr auto GetElements_helper(std::integer_sequence<uint16_t, I...>, std::integer_sequence<uint16_t, J...>)
    {
        constexpr std::array arr{I...};
        return std::tuple<typename Recast<std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + J + 1, uint16_t {})>::type...>{};
    }

    static constexpr auto GetElements()
    {
        return GetElements_helper(std::integer_sequence<uint16_t, Elements::GetSize()...>{}, std::make_integer_sequence<uint16_t, sizeof...(Elements)>{});
    }
     ⋮
     ⋮
}
```

Comment: I think that the `std::accumulate` might be just what I need to overcome the "size can't be used as a constant" error I have been getting, but I have never used `std::integer_sequence` before and I'm wondering what its benefits are over a raw variadic template parameter. As far as I have read just now, doesn't `std::integer_sequence` just act the same as a variadic template parameter in that it expands into the same sequence of integers that you fed it?

Comment: @Ryoku Like I said, I’m not sure what exactly you were trying to do, but here I’m creating something like `<sum(N0), sum(N0, N1), sum(N0, N1, N2), sum(N0, N1, N2, N3, N4),…, sum(N0, N1, N2,…,Nk)>`, which maybe you can accomplish with only `accumulate`, but I’m not sure.

Comment: @Ryoku Also note `accumulate` was only made `constexpr` after c++20. Prior to c++20, you might have to implement your own accumulation function with the help of `integer_sequence`.

Comment: @Ryoku And I think you are right that the `integer_sequence<I…>` was not needed, you could do it as parameter pack directly. But `integer_sequence<J…>` is needed as it’s created with `make_integer_sequence`

Comment: I think I'm not understanding quite how `integer_sequence` works. If you feed it the sequence `I...= <1, 4, 6, 7>` doesn't it just act the same as a parameter pack itself? Does it add any extra features aside from being able to easily call the size of the parameter pack? You are right though I am trying to make sure that the offset for each element is the sum of the size of all nodes before it.  If I'm correct in understanding what the `make_integer_sequence<J...>` is doing, you are simply using that to expand out and iterate over the `arr` array you created which if its the case, is brilliant

Comment: @Ryoku Like you said, if you use a `integer_sequence` directly, it would be basically the same as passing a parameter pack. The reason you might want to use it is `make_integer_sequence`. `make_integer_sequence<int, 5>` generates `integer_sequence<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4>` for you, which means you can generate a parameter pack of an arbitrary size from a single number, which can further be used to iterate over another parameter pack.

Comment: Awesome I think this is exactly what I'm looking for thank you very much for helping me walkthrough and understand it as well

Comment: @Ryoku Pleasured to help :D. Do note that many functions from `<algorithms>` and `<numeric>` and more containers have been made `constexpr` since c++20, so it’s possible you can accomplish similar tasks with them directly.

Comment: That is a powerful tool to keep in mind, I'll have to look into it even more but from what I read so far I'm not getting any ideas for something that could do a more "direct job"; but I'm definitely gonna keep looking because a "cleaner" solution could really help long term.